# Dynamic Firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Dynamic Firestore rules ?

I have 2 collections and I control access but granting customClaim. Now if I have more and more collections rules will become long.

**Example**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /india/{documentID} {
    allow read, write : if request.auth.token.india_admin == true
    allow read : if  true
    }

  }

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /japan/{documentID} {
    allow read, write : if request.auth.token.japan_admin == true
    allow read : if  true
    }

  }

}
```

Is there a way I can **generalize** it by using **collection** name variable

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  You can use a wildcard in the collection name for the rule to make a variable that you can use to match custom claims in a rule.  Is that what you're trying to do?  It might help if you were more specific about saying what you want to secure, and the conditions under which you want to secure it.

Comment: I have many collections and I will have ${collection}.admin custom claim for some users. Now instead of hardcoding rules for each collection I want to write single rule where collection is variable

Comment: Doug Stevenson - yes you have captured my intent correctly

Comment: Could you edit your question with a sample that works for exactly one collection, so we can see specifically what you're trying to do?

Comment: `request.auth.token` is a [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map). I don't see a way to look up a key with concatenated string in there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You can look up values dynamically in a Map using the x[k] syntax in the docs you linked.  k can be an expression.

Comment: @DougStevenson Good catch, I see that now. I had clicked through to `List`, where `x[k]` syntax only allows an index and not a key.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing now allow unconditional read access to everything.  That's what `allow read: if true` does.

Try this, using a wildcard for the collection name:

```
match /{country}/{documentID} {
  allow read, write : if request.auth.token[country + "_admin"] == true;
}
```

Note that this has the side effect of being applied to ALL of your top-level collection, even those that don't represent a country.  If you use other top-level collections that require different rules, you might want to push all of your country-specific collection into subcollections under a single top-level collection.